# How force midori not to display "UTC+1"?

Tags: javascript, html

The browser of my brother in law displays the time within the format: "HH:MM:SS UTC+1".
We live in Paris, France so it's technically true but on the web admin page, the time is displayed without the utc+1 mention.

I have checked on different websites how not not display the last sentence even a "maxlength=6" in the HTML code

JS code:

```
<script>
  var myTimer = setInterval(setClock,1000);
  function setClock(){
  document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML=new Date().toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'}).replace(/(:d{2}| [AP]M)$/, "");
  }
</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<div align="center"><p id="clock"></p></div>
```

I see the time like that:
21:51:22 UTC+1 on his browser but on the webpage, I see 21:51:22.

Please advise me on it.
Thanks

Comment: What you want to achieve? Method you presented new Date(...) is currently displaying without UTC suffix.

Comment: Yes I want this browser to display only the time without the 'utc+1' mention. The date with the mention takes too much space on the screen